# select all data of two different table using case

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

**There is 3 table**

1. **register_user**
2. **customer**
3. **employee**

i need to write query like below

```
select 
(case 
when register_user_type='E' then select * from employee where employee_id=register_user_id 
else select * from customer where employee_id=register_user_id
end
) 
from register_user
```

how to perform this query ?

Comment: It's impossible to give a useful answer with so little info to go with. Help us help you and provide the tables' structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ("SO") it may be easy to forget that we know absolutely nothing about your tables (and we cannot guess that detail) so you need to provide details to get an answer. If in doubt use the **[help]** on how to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to achieve something like the following?

```
SELECT IF(register_user_type='E', emp.col1, cust.col1), 
       IF(register_user_type='E', emp.col2, cust.col2)
FROM register_user AS user
JOIN employee AS emp ON emp.employee_id = user.register_user_id
JOIN customer AS cust ON cust.employee_id = emp.employee_id
```

You would have to individually list all the columns (col1, col2). I'm not aware of there being a way to use the asterisk (*) for such a query.